# .NET Core 2.2 Razor Page Code Behind Creates Text File, But Fails to Write Simple Line To File

Tags: c#, razor-pages, system.io.file

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I can create a text file named using Now date and time. My writing to the file fails. If I don't put ".Close()" at the end of the CreateText, it says the file is open by another process when trying to write. With the ".Close()" there are no errors but it doesn't write.

```
var newFileName = "logs\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/","_").Replace(":","-").Replace(" ","__") + ".txt";
var webRootPath = _environment.WebRootPath;
var dataPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, newFileName);
System.IO.File.CreateText(dataPath).Close();
System.IO.File.AppendText(dataPath).WriteLine("this is before save");
```

Comment: “other process” could be “same process” - error message isn’t always the best. Files in windows are generally opened as Exclusive and must be closed so that they can be reopened by other code (in the same process or otherwise). Without a “Close” or “Dispose” the file handle is left open for an undermined amount of time. Look up the ‘using’ statement for how to better manage resource lifetimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this:

```
//System.IO.File.CreateText(dataPath).Close();
System.IO.File.AppendText(dataPath).WriteLine("this is before save");
```

CreateText() will create a new empty file each time.

AppendText() will create the file if necessary.

But you are leaking file handles here. Appendtext returns a TextWriter that needs to be closed.

Instead of fixing that, consider using a reliable logging packages.

Comment: How do I close it? I tried AppendText 2 times and the second one bombed with the error: "IOException: The process cannot access the file '  ' because it is being used by another process." Now this is because it needs to be closed. I am having hard time figuring out the syntax to close it.

Comment: Yes. I will use logging. Right now I need a simple line or 2 in a simple text file. I can't seem to write the second line (after Save) to the same file. It error's saying it is being used. Even if I try .AppendAllLines. Every example I can find shows tons of ways to write once, but not later again.

Comment: AppendAllLines() will work if it is the _only_ thing you use.

Comment: Henk, you are correct! Thank you.             System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(dataPath, new[] { "this is before save" });

            System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(dataPath, new[] { "this is AFTER SAVE" });